# Add Active class on scroll

Tags: jquery

I have some sections im working on and i am trying to add active color class when scrolling sections. the active class just changes the color of the link when scrolled.

```
<div class="scrollLink">    
    <ul>
        <li class="link"><a href="#one">link</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="#two">link</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="#three">link</a></li>
    </ul>      
</div>

<section id="one">content</section>
<section id="two">content</section>
<section id="three">content</section>



var sections = $('section')
  , nav = $('li')
  , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');

      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You want to add colours to which elements ? It would also be much easier for us to help you, if you could share a jsfiddle with your code.